# getting one div size to resize an other one after a load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div containing other div and I need to dynamically refresh this kind of parent div.
To do that im using jquery to load a php file with args.

This php file creates 2 others divs inside the first one.

The first one contains items of the same size and is basically around 600px on a usual screen.

The second one could contains very long text and i want to resize it accordingly to the first div height cause on large screen, both div are side by side.

The parent div :
`<div id="modStart" class="row mt-5 pt-3">`

The first dynamic div :

```
<div id = "modC" class="col-xl-5 col-lg-12 mb-4">
  <div class="tm-bg-gray p-5 h-100">
    <?php
      //embed a video,a title and a button. Almost constant height but still depending on title length.
    ?>                              
  </div>                                
</div>
```

The second dynamic div (that I need to resize):

```
<div id = "modbC" class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12 mb-4">
  <div id = "modb2C" class="tm-bg-white p-5 h-100" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
    <?php
      // very long dynamic text
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the js function i'am calling to refresh the parent div

```
    function refreshMod(nMod)
    {
        $("#modStart").load("form_CSifr.php?currMod=" + nMod.toString(),function() 
        {
                var offsetHeight = document.getElementById("modC").offsetHeight;
                
                //DBG
                alert(offsetHeight.toString()); 
                // always the height of the very long content of the second div ...
                // so i guess it's too late here. 
                // I tried this code before filling the second div content but same rsult.

                document.getElementById("modbC").style.height = offsetHeight + "px";
                document.getElementById("modb2C").style.height = offsetHeight + "px";
        }); 
    }
```

I tried to get size and resize of different items. But I'm stuck now. No more ideas.

Im new to bootstrap and all those div are contained in

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div id="content" class="mx-auto tm-content-container">
```

Maybe I can't do that here.

Last thing, it used to work before i separet the code in another php file to reload only this div.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can simply use method `height()` without any parameters to get first div height and apply it to the other div, again using `height()` method this time with parameter:

```js
const leftDivHeight = $('#modC').height();
$('#modbC').height(leftDivHeight);
```